# Invoking aws lambda without output file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I'm trying to invoke a lambda on AWS using CLI:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name GetErrorLambda --payload '{"body":"{\"Id\":[\"321\",\"123\"]}"}' \output.
```

I would like to know if there's a way to print the output on the cli instead of create a file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not possible to output directly to the terminal after invoking a lambda function. This is likely by design as the output could easily be greater than the buffer size for a window.

A simple workaround would be to simply 'cat' out the contents of the output file following the cli command like so:

`aws lambda invoke --function-name GetErrorLambda --payload '{"body":"{\"Id\":[\"321\",\"123\"]}"}' \output. && cat outputFileName.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try with that.

Answer (score 66):

stdout and stderr are basically files so can be used for arguments that expect one

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name GetErrorLambda --payload '{"body":"{\"Id\":[\"321\",\"123\"]}"}' /dev/stdout
```

though in this case the rest of the commands output will overlap with it, so probably better to cat it later anyways

Comment: This is the exact answer

Comment: This is a better answer but note that you will get both the return value from your lambda function printed to stdout along with the return of the call to 'invoke'.

Comment: Any idea how to get he payload accepted in version 2 that is not base64 and not coming from a file?

Comment: See: `cli_binary_format=raw-in-base64-out` ~/.aws/config  . https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html#cliv2-migration-binaryparam

Answer (score 13):

I use following command:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name name --payload '{...}' /dev/stdout 2>/dev/null
```

The idea is redirect command output to `stderr` and the function result to `stdout`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use your current tty as the outfile, which allows command output to still be redirected:

```
> aws lambda invoke --function-name name --payload '{}' $(tty) >/dev/null
LAMBDA_OUTPUT
```

---

Using `/dev/stdout` for the outfile sort of works. Issue #1: the command output gets mixed up with it:

```
> aws lambda invoke --function-name name --payload '{}' /dev/stdout
{ACTUAL_OUTPUT
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

Issue #2: If you try to redirect the stdout then you've just directed the lambda result as well. You can at least separate them by piping to `cat`:

```
> aws lambda invoke --function-name name --payload '{}' /dev/stdout | cat
ACTUAL_OUTPUT{
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

Comment: aws lambda invoke --function-name greetingsOnDemand --payload "$payload" $(tty) >/dev/null --- Windows 10 git bash - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/pty0'

Answer (score 3):

Using a Bourne shell and for systems that support `/dev/fd/<n>`, you can duplicate stdout to a new file descriptor and use it for aws output:

```
exec 3>&1; aws lambda invoke --function-name Func /dev/fd/3 >/dev/null
```

You can also use that with pipeline:

```
{ exec 3>&1; aws lambda invoke --function-name Func /dev/fd/3 >/dev/null; } | cat
```

Or with command substitution:

```
out=$({ exec 3>&1; aws lambda invoke --function-name Func /dev/fd/3 >/dev/null; })
```

Comment: This can be done without the `;` in the same invocation:
`aws lambda invoke --function-name Func /dev/fd/3 3>&1 >/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

I would output it to a file and then cat it, but also redirect the regular output so the only thing printed is from the lambda invocation:

`aws lambda invoke --function-name GetErrorLambda --payload '{"body":"{\"Id\":[\"321\",\"123\"]}"}' out >>log && cat out`

You can also add  `&& echo` to the end of it to echo a new line.